# jsonp GET request 404 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io, jsonp

I'm using Nodejs, Socket.io, and Angular to build a web app taking advantage of the Instagram Real-Time API. I'm running into an issue when I fire off GET requests to the Instagram API.

I get this error every time I send a GET request:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"
```

The error details reveal:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/geographies/[object%20Object]/media/recent?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

Obviously that `[object%20Object]` is where the error lies. As my code below shows, that should be the 'geo_id' which I'm passing in as an argument. Geo_id is actually the 'object_id' of the Instagram real-time subscription.

Below is my code. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Socket.io server side code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // log user connections
    console.log("user connected");

    // receive the Instagram handshake for real-time subscriptions
    app.get('/callback', function(req, res){
        var handshake =  Instagram.subscriptions.handshake(req, res);
    });

    // for each new post Instagram sends us the data
    app.post('/callback', function(req, res) {
        var data = req.body;
        // grab the object_id (as geo_id) of the subscription and send as an argument   to the client side
        data.forEach(function(data) {
            var geo_id = data.object_id;
            sendUpdate(geo_id);
        });
        res.end();
    });

// send the url with the geo_id to the client side
// to do the ajax call
function sendUpdate(geo_id) {
    io.sockets.emit('newImage', { geo_id: geo_id });
}

    // log user disconnections
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

relevant angular controller code:

```
socket.on('newImage', function(geo_id) {
    // pass geo_id into Instagram API call
    Instagram.get(geo_id).success(function(response) {
        instagramSuccess(response.geo_id, response);
    });

    // Instagram API callback
    var instagramSuccess = function(scope,res) {
        if (res.meta.code !== 200) {
            scope.error = res.meta.error_type + ' | ' + res.meta.error_message;
            return;
        }
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
            $scope.items = res.data;
        } else {
            scope.error = "This location has returned no results";
        }
    };
});
```

Instagram angular factory code:

```
angular.module('InstaFactory', []).factory('Instagram', function($http) {
    var base = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";
    var client_id = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';

    return {
        'get': function(geo_id) {
            var request = '/geographies/' + geo_id + '/media/recent?client_id=' + client_id;
            var url = base + request;
            var config = {
                'params': {
                    'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                }
            };
            return $http.jsonp(url, config);
        }
    };
```

});

Comment: Your `GET` and `POST` Express routes should be defined *outside* of your socket.io connection handler.

Comment: your `geo_id` variable is an object that has a property named `geo_id` that holds the value, you need to use the variable as an object: `geo_id.geo_id` to get the value

Comment: @mscdex, how would I manage to emit a socket event if this code is outside my connection handler?

Comment: You're not emitting anything on `socket`, you're using `io.sockets.emit()` which is available outside of your socket.io `connection` handler. The way the `connection` handler code currently is, you are **adding** two Express routes every time a new socket.io connection is made.